# Opencart product category - division by zero

Tags: opencart, division, zero

I've been working on an e-commerece site - www.bestbargain.lk
and I've encountered the following error in Open Cart 1.5.2

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/43/10031243/html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_category.php on line 200

This error appears only in product category pages in which has one or more nested categories with products. Main category pages with no sub categories does not have this problem.

The following gets the error:
Computer Accessories -> Mouse | Subwoofer | Webcam
http://bestbargain.lk/index.php?route=product/category&path=18

But this doesnt have the error:
Mobile Phones
http://bestbargain.lk/index.php?route=product/category&path=25

Any help or explanation is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a modification of some sort on the controller, hence it being a vqcache file rather than the actual file path. I would recommend disabling your vqmods one by one until you find the culprit, starting with those that you think are modifying your category pages

Comment: Please elaborate on disabling "those". You mean disable extensions? or mods?

Answer (score 0):

If limit value is not integer, this error occurs

ALL FIND

```
if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
```

ALL REPLACE

```
if (isset($this->request->get['limit']) && (int)$this->request->get['limit']) {
```